# Positioning a div or dialog to the center of the window

Tags: jquery

I am using this following code to position the dialog to the center of the window.

```
var dialog = $('#dialogBox');
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var dHeight = $('#dialogBox').height();
var dWidth = $('#dialogBox').width();
$('#dialogBox').css({top:windowHeight/2 - dHeight/2, left:windowWidth/2 - dWidth/2}).show();
```

It positions the div to the center of the window. But i wants to position the dialog to the center of current visible area. So the dialog will be positioned center of the window even if i scroll down or scroll up. How to do it with jquery?

Any suggestions would be appreciative!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make it dead-centered like this:

```
$('#elementID').css({
  position:'absolute',
  top:'50%',
  left:'50%',
  width:'600px',                 // adjust width
  height:'300px',                // adjust height
  zIndex:1000,
  marginTop:'-150px'             // half of height
  marginLeft:'-300px'            // half of width
});
```

Note that element will appear at the center but with scrolling it won't move. If you want to make it appear at center, you need to set `position` to `fixed` instead. However, this won't work in IE6. So decision is yours :)

---

You can also create quick simple jQuery plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.centerIt = function(settings){

        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.centerIt.defaults, settings);

        return this.each(function(settings){
          var options = $.extend({}, opts, $(this).data());
          var $this = $(this);

          $this.css({
            position:options.position,
            top:'50%',
            left:'50%',
            width:options.width,                 // adjust width
            height:options.height,               // adjust height
            zIndex:1000,
            marginTop:parseInt((options.height / 2), 10) + 'px'  // half of height
            marginLeft:parseInt((options.width / 2), 10) + 'px'  // half of height
          });

        });
    }

    // plugin defaults - added as a property on our plugin function
    $.fn.centerIt.defaults = {
      width: '600px',
      height: '600px',
      position:'absolute'
    }

})(jQuery);
```

And later use it like:

```
$('#elementId').centerIt({width:'400px', height:'200px'});
```

Comment: Our app only runs from !E 7 :)

Comment: @TamilVendhan: Welcome, I have updated the answer though. Have fun :)

Comment: The code is missing two ',' but since it is only 2 characters i can't edit it :D. anyway this isn't work on chrome as it pushes the div to the bottom

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to change CSS attribute position to this:
**position: fixed**

Not sure if it works in IE, it didn't in versions 7 an older. This will maintain that dialog in the same position relative to the window, even if you scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very light weight function to center a element to the screen. The only thing I haven't included is the z-index but this can be easily added.

```
$.fn.centerToWindow = function()
{
  var obj           = $(this);
  var obj_width     = $(this).outerWidth(true);
  var obj_height    = $(this).outerHeight(true);
  var window_width  = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();
  var window_height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();

  obj.css({
    "position" : "fixed",
    "top"      : ((window_height / 2) - (obj_height / 2))+"px",
    "left"     : ((window_width / 2) - (obj_width / 2))+"px"
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this help, but jQuery UI has some pretty nice dialog box possibility with a centering option. You should maybe consider using them instead of writing your own.

see : http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/